# How to find the common nearest neighbour vertex of given k different vertices in an undirected weighted graph?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, discrete-mathematics

Given an undirected weighted graph G(V,E). and any three vertices let u, v and w. Find a vertex x of G. such that dist(u,x) + dist(v,x) + dist(w,x) is minimum.
x could be any vertex in G (u, v and w included). is there exits any particular algorithm for this problem?

Comment: It will be hard to do better than O(log |V|), because the fastest known algorithm for finding the shortest path between 2 points (Dijkstra's algorithm with a Fibonacci heap) takes O(|E| + |V|log |V|) time, and if you had an o(log |V|) algorithm to solve your problem, you could solve the shortest path problem between points u and v in better time by calling your algorithm |V|-2 times, with w being each of the other vertices in turn, and building a path from the vertices w for which the return value x was also w.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would you want to find this vertex? For which scenario is it interesting?

Comment: I was doing a network setup. The vertex x would be the place where I put my servers. and u, v and w would be my workplaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with stack algorithm like the pseudo-code below:

```
void FindNeigh(node node1, node node2,int graphsize)
{
    byte[graphsize] isGraphProcessed; // 0 array

    stack nodes1, nodes2; //0 arrays
    nodes1.push(node1);
    nodes2.push(node2);
    bool found = false;

    while(!nodes1.empty && !nodes2.empty())
    {
        stack tmp = null;
        for(node: nodes1)
            for(neigh : node.neighbors)
                if(!isGraphProcessed[neigh.id])
                {
                    tmp.push(neigh.id);
                    isGraphProcessed[neigh.id] = 1; // Flags for node 1
                }
                else if(isGraphProcessed[neigh.id] == 2) // The flag of node 2 is set
                    return neigh;
        nodes1 =tmp;
        tmp = null;
        for(node: nodes2)
            for(neigh : node.neighbors)
                if(!isGraphProcessed[neigh.id])
                {
                    tmp.push(neigh.id);
                    isGraphProcessed[neigh.id] = 2; // Flags for node 2
                }
                else if(isGraphProcessed[neigh.id] == 1) // The flag of node 1 is set
                    return neigh;
        nodes2 = tmp;
    }
    return NULL; // don't exist
}
```

**How does it work**

- You start from both edges of the graph
- You check neighbors in a stack
- If a neighbor have already been added in the stack of the other node, that mean that it have already been reached by the other node --> He is the closest node. We return it.
- If nothing is found, we do the same thing with the neighbour of the neigbors (and so on recursively) until something is found.
- If node2 can't be reached from node1 it returns 0.

Note : This algorithm works to find the minimal distance between 2 edges. If you want to do it for 3 edges you can add a 3rd stack and look for the first node having the 3 flags (e.g. 1, 2 and 4).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit. I want to know the procedure.

Comment: The graph in discussion here is a weighted graph. the solution will not work in all the cases. remember I need a node with minimum of  dist(u,x) + dist(v,x) + dist(w,x).

Comment: I read too fast. I think that you can just replace the stacks by SortedLists (sorted by weight) and add neighbors normally (neigh.cost = me.cost + edge.cost). Always choose the node with the smallest cost.

Answer (score 1):

If `k` is large and there are no negative edge cost cycles then Floyd Warshall's Algorithm can work. It runs in `O(|V|^3)` time and after its completion we have the entire shortest distance matrix and we can get the shortest distances between any two vertices in `O(1)` time. Then just scan and look for the best vertex `x` that gives the least sum of total distance value from the `k` vertices.

Comment: See here the question is not to find the shortest distance.

Comment: @user2242017 To calculate dist(u,x) + dist(v,x) + dist(w,x), you need to know dist(u,x) which is the shortest distance between u and x.